# How to insert UISegmentedControl in UINavigationBar like AppStore app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to know how to create a `UINavigationBar` with a `UISegmentedControl` inside like in AppStore app in iOS 7 and 8.

[image]

Seems that the height of `UINavigationBar` was increased in order to contain also the `UISegmentedControl`.

Does anyone know the best way to do this ?
Thanks.